# Loop over unique values to compare groups in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to compare users in different groups using a loop. I've included a sample dataframe below and one initial attempt (that ends in error). I'd like to know how to iterate over each unique value in a dataframe and then select rows conditional within the values for that user.

So, in the example attempt below, I have a score for "before" and "after" in column D. If I try to get a ratio of before/after, I looped over the `set()` of users and then subsetted each iteration of the loop when `iterrows()` finds a row in the dataframe where user == i. This didn't work, but I hope it gives you an idea of how I'm approaching the problem.

I'll say that I know loops aren't always considered best practice in Pandas, but in the larger dataframe, I want to perform a bunch of different comparison functions between groups and being able to do it in a flexible loop has advantages, so I'm hoping someone will help me with this approach (where I loop over each unique user).

[Edit]: the expected output would be (pseudo-code):

```
User: 1, ratio: 0.5
User: 2, ratio: 1.7
```

Thanks and let me know if I can make this question as more clear.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"user": [1,2,1,2],
                   "B": ["before", "before", "after", "after"],
                   "D": [1, 5, 2, 3],
                   "E": [2, 4, 5, 5]})

for item, row in df.iterrows():
  s = set(df.user)
  for i in s:
    if row.user == i:
      row[row["B"] == 'before']['D'] / row[row["B"] == 'after']['D']
```

Comment: Can you add expected output?

Comment: @HenryYik added!